# Wrong syntax indicate in Scala template syntax

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, intellij-14

When I use SBT import play project to IDEA, it works almost perfectly but `view.html` (scala syntax ) indicate wrong error:

[image: Template error]

Comment: Did you have installed Scala Plugin? Also, looks like you are using the wrong editor for the `scala.html` file type. Check it at `Preferences -> Editor -> File Types`.

Comment: thanks @marcospereira scala plugin was installed.